# Remove ellipsis (&helip;) after sub-string concatenation

Tags: php, html, substring, concatenation

I am concatenating two sub-strings with an ellipsis (...) added at the end of the first sub-string. However I want this elipsis to be removed after the concatenation. 
Is this possible via a script or other means, Thanks:

`<?php echo substr($post_text_result2, 0, 400) . "&hellip;";?><div id="second_post" class = "hidden"><?php echo substr($post_text_result2, 400, 5000);?></div>`:

str_replace deletes the elipsis like requested, however does not fully work in my situation:
The code below works however, The first sub-string is repeated. I need a way to remove the first sub-string.

```
<?php
$string = substr($post_text_result2, 0, 400) . "&hellip;"; 
echo $string;
?>

<div id="second_post" class = "hidden">

<?php       
$string= str_replace('&hellip;','',$string); echo $string;
echo $string;
echo substr($post_text_result2, 400, 5000);
?>
```

Comment: Why not just add the strings without the ellipses in the first place?

Comment: I want the elipsis because the concatenation occurs when a button is pressed.
I am using it for the expanding of a blog post, so I want an elipsis to show that the blog can be expanded

Comment: But why you can't use the strings, when the button is pressed, before the concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the length of the first string A and then build a new string concatenating 2 substrings:

```
substring 1 from 0 until length(A) - 3

substring 2 from length(A) until total length
```

You also could use a regex and replace "..." with "", but that could remove other "..." which is maybe unwanted.

Sorry for no code, I can't PHP but you know how to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

easy

```
<?php

$string = substr($post_text_result2, 0, 400) . "&hellip;";
$string = str_replace('&hellip;','',$string);

?>
```

If you want an ellipsis always at the end, just do this:

```
<?php

$string = substr($post_text_result2, 0, 400) . "&hellip;";
$string = str_replace('&hellip;','',$string) . "&hellip;";

?>
```

Comment: but what if the string has other "..." before the "..." which has to be removed. Then the first ellipsis will be removed, which is unwanted, and the second one stays.

Comment: Ah no, that is incorrect. str_replace removes ALL ellipses as I have used it above. Are you saying that you only want to remove the last elipsis?

Comment: I'm not the OP. Just saying that is maybe unwanted that other ellipses besides the one he wants to remove, are removed (in both cases if all are removed or only the first one).

Comment: I think we need something more intelligible from OP.

Comment: OP here, I want the elipsis to show when only the firs sub-string shows. When the second sub-string concatenates with the first I want the elipsis to remove.

Comment: remove before concatenation still apply